# Drupal 10 rules mime mail html not sending

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules, drupal-10

I am using the latest version of Drupal 10 and have as advised by rules module installed mime mail module to be able to have rules send html email. I have to my knowledge set up all as per instruction. Test emails from symfony mail come through as HTML. Orders from commerce come through as html. Rules just doesn't seem to want to, no matter the variations I try.

I have setup a rules email send on cron run for test and have mime mail setup according to image. The html in message of rules is simply for testing:
"

**This text is bold**

*This text is italic*

This is <sub>subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup>

"

and I continue to get plain text.
[image: Mail System Settings]
[image: Mail Sysyem Settings 2]
[image: Mime Mail Settings]

Any guidance appreciated

I have tried variances of the settings and am getting HTML emails from system just not from drupal rules.